# Java Android Full Screen Closing

Tags: android, fullscreen

I am testing this code to see if it takes the title away from the GUI but it makes the program crash.  I was trying to add `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` but that didn't work.

```
package com.example.marcus.game;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.marcus.game.MainActivity"
android:background="#5a23f3">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Games"
    android:id="@+id/gamesText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:autoText="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E23v7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in starting of `onCreate()` like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //ADD HERE
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't crash now but the title is still there

Comment: i want what is circled in that pic i added above gone